# Run script on clicked div only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a smal portfolio with images and I want to show text (info) when this images are clicked. Fade or slide away the image and show the text "behind" when the div is clicked. When the div is clicked again, hide text and show image.

This fiddle I made may clear this up.
http://jsfiddle.net/0sr26qf4/

Question is, as you may see, all the div responds to the script. Only the clicked div have to show the text. I have tried with jQuery .next() but don't get this to work properly.

```
$(".text").hide();
$(".container").click(function(){
$("#image, #text").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

**SOLUTION:**

This worked like a charm :) Also changed id to class, thank you for this!

```
$(".text").hide();
$(".container").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".image, .text").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: ID's are unique, you can't use an ID more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use Id's multiple times on your page. You have to change it to class.

Updated HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">image 1</div>
    <div class="text">
        info image 1 <br><br> 
        <a href="www.google.se">link</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="image">image 2</div>
    <div class="text">
        info image 2 <br><br> 
        <a href="www.google.se">link</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="image">image 3</div>
    <div class="text">
        info image 3 <br><br> 
        <a href="www.google.se">link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to pass reference to your clicked object by using $(this) word.

JavaScript:

```
$(".text").hide();
$(".container").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".image, .text").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0sr26qf4/1/

Answer (score 2):

Jquery [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(".text").hide();
$(".container").click(function(){
  $(this).find("#image, #text").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[<kbd>Updated Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/0sr26qf4/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use `this` as second parameter in selector(second parameter provides the context in which to search the element matched by the first selector):

```js
$(".text").hide();
$(".container").click(function() {
  $("#image, #text", this).slideToggle("slow");//add this to selector
});
```

```css
#image {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#text {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="image">image 1</div>
  <div id="text" class="text">info image 1
    <br>
    <br> <a href="www.google.se">link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="image">image 2</div>
  <div id="text" class="text">info image 2
    <br>
    <br> <a href="www.google.se">link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="image">image 3</div>
  <div id="text" class="text">info image 3
    <br>
    <br> <a href="www.google.se">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just to add that ID must be unique and you should use class instead.